# Master Product list from multiple tables with the exact same column names

Tags: mysql

I’ve got quite a few tables with product information.  The columns on each table that I’m pulling from in this particular query have the exact same column names.  I’ve been attempting to do it via a UNION ALL but for some reason it is throwing an error saying non-object but all the column names are correct.

I’m using a format that  I found online.  But obviously something is wrong.  There are more tables; however, this is how it starts (with 2).  I’d prefer not to have to code each select statement in the union with unique table abbreviations if I don’t have to.

I don’t have to use union if there is a better method.

**All tables share data on Product_Categories and Product_Sub_Category.**

**The only thing unique to each table is id and part_number.**

```
SELECT f.id,f.part_number,f.cat,f.subcat,f.table_name FROM
(
SELECT t.id,t.part_number,psc.name as subcat,c.name as cat, c.table_name FROM Steel_Strapping as t JOIN Product_Sub_Category as psc ON t.subcat = psc.id JOIN Product_Categories as c ON psc.category = c.id ORDER BY c.sort_order,psc.sort_order,t.sort_order
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id,t.part_number,psc.name as subcat,c.name as cat, c.table_name FROM Product as t JOIN Product_Sub_Category as psc ON t.subcat = psc.id JOIN Product_Categories as c ON psc.category = c.id ORDER BY c.sort_order,psc.sort_order,t.sort_order
) f
```

**My end result is one full list of all products sharing column names.  Ex:  $result[‘part_number’] will pull part numbers from ALL tables listed in union.**

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you've tried. Have you run the individual queries of your union on their own? Have you run the whole query directly in the DB? I'm also confused about the purpose of the outer-query here.

Comment: I ended up not needing the outer query.  I tried that after a single query didnt work.  I was looking at examples as to what people were doing online with unions.  I tried each individual query yes.  The problem was that I needed parenthesis (select...)  UNION JOIN (select...) inside the query.  I guess with the joins in each select query, it threw off the main query.

Comment: I think the reason you need the parentheses is because you have an `ORDER BY` on the individual parts. If you had a single `ORDER BY` at the end of all of the `UNION`s (which I think makes more sense) I don't think you would need the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution when playing around with code.  I had to add parenthesis (select...) UNION JOIN (select...) inside the parent select statement